# Inmovilizar encabezados listas de sharepoint

Tags: javascript, json, sharepoint

Tengo una lista de sharepoint (office365) creada con 16 campos, y con muchos registros. Necesito saber cómo podría inmovilizar el encabezado para que al desplazarme hacia abajo se quede fijo y pueda visualizarlos desde cualquier registro?

He intentado crear código Json, con ejemplos que he buscado,  pero no funciona. Tengo esto que fue lo que encontré en este enlace... Pero no sirve, puesto que es otro lenguaje(que he [obtenido de esta fuente](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/es-ES/7f8b59e2-1206-4742-93aa-b7be7698f7ce/inmoviliar-la-barra-de-titulo-de-las-columnas-en-las-listas-y-bibliotecas-de-sharepoint?forum=mosses)):

```
<script
src="Link to jquery.js"
type="text/javascript"></script>
<style type="text/css">
<!--
.DataGridFixedHeader { position: relative; top: expression (this.offsetParent.scrollTop);}
-->
</style>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function(){
var $table = $("TABLE[ID^='{BFD03356-0ACF-4950-9C6C-D772A31E3E46}']:first",
"#MSO_ContentTable");
<!--WRAP TABLE IN SCROLL PANE-->
$table.wrap("<DIV style='OVERFLOW: auto; HEIGHT: " + (screen.height-400) + "px'></DIV>"); <!--FROZEN HEADER ROW--> $("TR.ms-viewheadertr:first", $table).addClass("DataGridFixedHeader");

});

</script>
```

¿Alguien sabría decirme qué código  puedo utilizar?
Agradezco mucho la ayuda.

Comment: Bienvenido, podrías compartir el código de lo que haz intentado?

Comment: @SalvaSolbes [Bienvenido a Stack Overflow en Español](http://es.stackoverflow.com/tour). Este no es un sitio para solicitar código. Para que la comunidad entienda mejor su pregunta, debe leer [cómo crear una buena pregunta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) y [cómo crear un ejemplo mínimo, completo y verificable](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Luego [edit] la pregunta.

Answer (score 0):

mira este [enclance en ingles](http://spoodoo.com/sticky-headers-in-sharepoint-2013/), es un script que sirve para crear los "sticky headers" o cabezeras fijas, en las tablas de SharePoint.

epero que te sea de ayuda.